# Can I perform a chi-squared analysis with a categorical variable and the means of a continuous variable?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, continuous-data

I have one variable that is categorical (with 5 levels), and another variable that consists of either mean or sum scores (0 to 28) due to the way you have to calculate the scores of this measure.

Can I perform a chi-squared test with my categorical data and sum scores?

Comment: Do you have the original data that the means were calculated from? Do you just want to test for association, or do you think of 1 of the variables as a response?

Comment: I do have the original data, which are responses in three areas of X that are computated together to give one score of X. I want to test for association.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a chi-squared test in this way.  The simplest approach would be to use a one-way ANOVA, with the categorical variable as your independent variable and the combined X as your response.  You could also do a MANOVA, using the three areas of X as distinct multiple responses.  However, that would be more complicated, and if there is an a-priori theoretical reason to see the combined X as a single variable, you are OK to skip it.